# Adding stylesheet from plugins folder to front end, inside of plugin

Tags: php, css, function, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpess plugin and I need the stylesheet to be loaded onto the front-end (included in wp_head). The plugin's stylesheet is vital so it will show up on the front-end.

How can I achieve this?

I've tried several methods such as enqueing but it doesn't show up. Perhaps I'm placing the code in the wrong file?

As you can see below, I do enqueue the scripts and styles but it only shows up on the edit screens and not on the front-end like i need it too.

```
function input_admin_enqueue_scripts()
{



    // register scripts
    wp_register_script('input-icon_field', $this->settings['dir'] . 'js/input.js', array('input'), $this->settings['version']);
    wp_register_style('input-icon_field', $this->settings['dir'] . 'css/input.css', array('input'), $this->settings['version']);


    // scripts
    wp_enqueue_script(array(
        'input-icon_field',
    ));

    // styles
    wp_enqueue_style(array(
        'input-icon_field',
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing array from wp_enqeue_script

```
function input_admin_enqueue_scripts() {

        // register scripts
        wp_register_script('input-icon_field', $this->settings['dir'] . 'js/input.js', array('input'), $this->settings['version']);
        wp_register_style('input-icon_field', $this->settings['dir'] . 'css/input.css', array('input'), $this->settings['version']);


        // scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('input-icon_field');

        // styles
        wp_enqueue_style('input-icon_field');

    }
```

and add an action to this function like so

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'input_admin_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out. i was putting it in the wrong file.